# Expected expression and undeclared identifier error

Tags: c, pointers, struct

When I initialize a pointer to a struct variable all in one line, I get `error: expected expression`, but if I define the variable before without the declaration it works. I want to define all the struct pointers in one line, without doing a forward declaration first, because if not then my file will get pretty long.

Any suggestions on how I can fix these issues? Or is there no way to circumvent this issue?

```
...
//a Node class is defined before, similar to a Node in a linked list

struct Node *buildast(struct Node *t) {
  int tag = node_get_tag(t);

  switch (tag) {
      //i dont want to keep declaring my variables likes below
      struct Node *root;
      struct Node *everything_else;
    
    case NODE_translation_unit:
      //To fix my issue, I declared my variables before
      root = node_alloc_str_copy(AST_ROOT, node_get_str(t));
      everything_else = node_get_kid(t, 0);
      node_add_kid(root, everything_else);
      return buildast(everything_else);

    case NODE_definition: 
        //i want to define my struct pointert to a Node in
        //one line like below but get an error
        //when I try to use the below variable later, I get an 
        //undeclared identifier to 'child'
       struct Node *child = node_get_kid(t, 0); //this line gives an error
       if (node_get_num_kids(child) <= 1) {
        node_add_kid(t, child);
        return buildast(child);
       }
       
       ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem:

```
case NODE_definition: 
   struct Node *child = node_get_kid(t, 0);
```

Because you're applying a label to a *declaration*.  A label can only be applied to a *statement*.

A simple way to do this without restructuring is to add a null statement right after the `case` label:

```
case NODE_definition: 
   ;
   struct Node *child = node_get_kid(t, 0);
```

Or use a compound statement:

```
case NODE_definition: 
{
   struct Node *child = node_get_kid(t, 0);
    ...
}
```

Generally speaking however your code would be cleaner by putting any declarations *before* the `switch` so you don't need to define anything inside of it and worry about these types of issues.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that this ...

> When I initialize a pointer to a struct variable all in one line, I get `error: expected expression`, but if I define the variable before without the declaration it works.

... is intended to describe the error flagged for this ...

```
    case NODE_definition: 
        //i want to define my struct pointert to a Node in
        //one line like below but get an error
        //when I try to use the below variable later, I get an 
        //undeclared identifier to 'child'
       struct Node *child = node_get_kid(t, 0); //this line gives an error
```

... you have misunderstood the nature of the problem.  And if indeed the error message emitted for that was "expected expression" then you should switch to a better compiler, because that diagnostic is extremely misleading.

Contrast with GCC's diagnostic for the same line:

> ```
> t.c:11:13: error: a label can only be part of a statement and a declaration is not a statement
>              struct node *child = node_get_kid(t, 0);
> ```

If you rely on a previous declaration of variable `child`, then the what's left ...

```
             child = node_get_kid(t, 0);
```

... is a statement, and therefore can be labelled.  Although it is in fact an *expression statement*, consisting of an expression, all other kinds of statements are also allowed there -- a `break;` statement, for example.  It is not true that an expression is required.

As for using the variable later, a variable declaration is scoped to the innermost block (if any) containing it, which in this case is the `switch` body.  If you want to use the variable outside the `switch` then you must declare it before the `switch` (not just before the `case` label):

```
  struct Node *child;

  switch (tag) {

    // ...

    case NODE_definition: 
        child = node_get_kid(t, 0);

    // ...
  }

  // you can still use 'child' here
```

If you only want it for the one `case`, then you can insert it into a block (a.k.a. a *compound statement*):

```
  switch (tag) {

    // ...

    case NODE_definition: {
        struct Node *child = node_get_kid(t, 0);

        // ...

        // the above declaration of 'child' is in scope (only) up to this point
    }
```